# ReactJS - Unable to import scss globally across components

Tags: reactjs, sass

I am using create-react-app (without ejection) for one of my application, and have the following folder structure:

```
/src
    assets
        scss
            abstract
                _variables.scss
                _mixins.scss
        _global.scss
    components
        Welcome
            Welcome.js
            Welcome.scss
    App.js    
    App.scss
```

The contents of the files are below:

**_variables.scss**

```
$color-info: #f45a40;
```

**global.scss**

```
@import "./abstract/variables";
@import "./abstract/mixins";
```

**App.scss**

```
@import "assets/scss/global";
```

**App.js**

```
import React from "react";
import "./App.scss"
import Welcome from "./components/Welcome"


const App = () => {
  return (
    <Welcome />
  );
};

export default App;
```

**Welcome.js**

```
import React from "react";
import "./Welcome.scss"

const Welcome = () => {
  return (
    <div class="text-color">Some test here</div>
  );
};

export default Welcome;
```

**Welcome.scss**

```
.text-color {
    color: $color-info;
}
```

Since i am already including the "global.scss" in "App.scss", should it not automatically make all partials available for components like "Welcome.js"? Unfortunately its not, its throwing me the following error in "Welcome.scss" file:

> SassError: Undefined variable: "$color-info".

But, if I include 'global.scss' in the "Welcome.scss" file, then it works fine. I do not want to include global.scss in each and every component, is there a way to make this work?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Webpack then you have multiple ways to achive that, for example:

1. Sass-loader `additionalData` option. You set some string and it will be prepended before actual file contents.
   https://webpack.js.org/loaders/sass-loader/#additionaldata
2. Sass-resources-loader, mostly will do the same, but have more options to configure.
   https://github.com/shakacode/sass-resources-loader

Comment: No, I am using create-react-app without ejection. Please help me achieve my goal.

Comment: I am not sure that this is possible without eject in CRA. You probably would need to import variables manually in each file. If there is a way to do it automatically I would like to know too.

Comment: The problem here is if i include the partials i.e "variables.scss" or "mixins.scss" manually in each and every component, then there will be multiple instances of css classes when i inspect in chrome dev tools. Isnt that redundant css data?

Comment: you can try with "react-app-rewired"

Answer (score 0):

I understand that you wanted to create a theme imported to the parent React component.

Unfortunately, Sass does not provide this possibility. You have to import variables into a sass file every time.

But I can tell you that the Styled-components library provides a possibility for React.js

If you want to learn about creating a theme in Styled-components please check: https://styled-components.com/docs/advanced#theming.

Comment: Is this a sass issue or React? Because if i compile globall.scss to global.css and include it in the public/index.html file as a normal css link tag then it works.